# Is there is a way to bucket a column in R that has numeric/text values?

Tags: r

Column size has values like these: "70" "S"  "M"  "L"  "X"  "60" "62" "46" "50" "54" "46" "50" "54" "60"
[31] "NA" "50" "54" "58" "62" "44" "50" "54" "58" "44" "40" "

I am trying create a bucket list in R that makes any size 70 or greater in "X", anything >= 60 and <70 in "L", anything >= 50 and <60 in "M", and anything >=40 "S". I am  new to R so I am confused on how to do this.  I have a column name size that have this information in it.  It is hard because I know in R the columns can only have on type of data. I change column size to numeric but then loose the text values I already have. Can someone help me? This is the code I am using:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(C02E02)) {
Xb <- C02E02[i,9]
Lb <- C02E02[1,9]

if (Xb >= "70"){
laXb <-Xb
}else {
C02E02[i,9] <- c("X")
}

if (Lb >= 60 & Lb<70){
laLb <-Lb
}else {
C02E02[i,9] <- c("L")
}

}
```

[image]

Comment: Easier to help if you provide a reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. `ifelse` should be able to do what you want here.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the index of all the values where there are only numbers, convert them to numeric and use `cut` to divide them into different groups and assign labels to them.

```
y <- x
inds <- grep('^\\d+$', y)
y[inds] <- as.character(cut(as.numeric(y[inds]), 
           c(0, 50, 60, 70, Inf), c('S', 'M', 'L', 'X'), right = FALSE))
y

# [1] "X"  "S"  "M"  "L"  "X"  "L"  "L"  "S"  "M"  "M"  "S"  "M"  "M"  "L"  "NA"
#[16] "M"  "M"  "M"  "L"  "S"  "M"  "M"  "M"  "S"  "S"
```

For your data replace `x` with `C02E02$Size`.

**data**

```
x <- c("70", "S", "M", "L", "X", "60", "62", "46", "50", "54", "46", 
"50", "54", "60", "NA", "50", "54", "58", "62", "44", "50", "54", 
"58", "44", "40")
```